# pre-commit + python + react (js)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I use pre-commit, I want to use it together with .py files, I reformat file  black module, but I also have a web folder where the react files are, I have 2 questions at once, what is relevant for reformatting the code for js and how can I unite so that when the pre-commit run is started, the web folder is checked for reformatting the js code

**UPDATE:**
the question that worried me the most is the js and py file conflict, but I used:

```yaml
  - repo: https://github.com/prettier/prettier
    rev: 2.1.2
    hooks:
      - id: prettier
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

though pre-commit is written in python, it has support for [many different programming languages](https://pre-commit.com/#supported-languages) including javascript

there's a whole list of supported tools [in the pre-commit documentation](https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html) -- the most popular probably being `eslint` or `prettier` (though, tool suggestion is generally off-topic on stack overflow since it's highly opinion based)

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit

Comment: the question that worried me the most is the js and py file conflict, but I used ```  - repo: https://github.com/prettier/prettier
    rev: 2.1.2
    hooks:
      - id: prettier```

Comment: ah, you can tell prettier to not run against python with `exclude` / `exclude_types`

Answer (score 1):

This is my config file for formatting React.js/React.ts using Prettier and pre-commit , if anyone is interested.  I have it set to single-quotes, but you can mess with the arguments as you desire.  Shoutouts to my brother for creating this amazing tool!

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/prettier/prettier
    rev: 2.1.1
    hooks:
      - id: prettier
        args: [--single-quote=true]
```